# How do native speakers read "comings"?

Tags: pronunciation

[sound track of "comings and goings"](https://soundcloud.com/xi-zhang-819295156/comings-and-goings)

I thought "comings" just read as "coming"+"s".

But this man read it like "co-mings".

What's your opinion?

Comment: The linked pronunciation is incorrect. (You say "this man", but to me it sounds like it might be artificially generated.)

Comment: That's definately not a human speaker and you should not use it to learn pronounciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the guy who is reading that short passage is not a real human. I have a strong suspicion that the audio snippet that you've got there was generated using one of those  speech synthesis programs. My guess would be that there might have been a mistake in the original text where instead of **comings** somebody wrote **combings** which is exactly what that "guy" appears to be saying. Listen to how native speakers pronounce **combing**: https://forvo.com/word/combing/#en (I hope you will notice that the *b* is completely silent). And then compare it with how they say **coming**: https://forvo.com/word/coming/#en. So, you were not wrong.